# Is there a way that I can assign permissions to folders within Azure Storage account File Share?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I've tried looking through Microsoft's documentation but I find it very hard to follow and I can't seem to get in touch with Azure Support unless I pay to upgrade my current license.
All I want to know is, is it possible to assign permissions on certain folders or files that are in the Azure File Share within the Storage Account?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to assign the user as [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) in folders or files in the Azure File Share, if so, you can't. 
Azure RBAC just supports blob and queue storage currently.

Reference - [Use the Azure portal to assign an RBAC role for access to blob and queue data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json)

Comment: Is there any way in which I can lock down access to certain folders through Azure File Share? I currently have a File Server On-Premises, but I'm looking to get it set up in the cloud, But, I'd like it if I could put the same restrictions on the folders on the Filer Server onto the Azure File Share. Is this possible at all? or is there a alternative method?